# Can I implement read-aloud myself for epub 3?

Tags: epub, ebook-readers, audiobooks

I wish to have an ebook where pressing the play button results in **only one paragraph** being played at a time. Also, the person reading the book should be able to press on certain words to see the definition of that word in other languages.

So I created an ebook with media overlays and implemented an onClick handler for each word I wish to display a definition for. However, when I loaded this into iBooks, it seems that iBooks redefined my onClick handlers. Instead, when I click on a word the audio beings to play from this point.

So, I was thinking I could implement the audio and paragraph highlighting (via smil file) myself using html5 and javascript instead of the reader itself doing it. This way I can define the exact behavior I want, with only one paragraph being played. Does this sound like a good strategy?